# Creating a child class from a parent method in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a class that has a bunch of children that all have their own respective methods but share common methods through the parent. The problem is I need to create an instance of the child class in the parent method but am not sure how to go about it

my code so far looks like this

```
def filterAttribute(self, attribute, value):
        newlist = []
        for thing in self._things:
            if thing._attributes[attribute] == value:
                newlist.append(thing)
        return self.__init__(newlist)
```

the class constructor takes in a list as its sole argument. Does anyone know if there is a standard way of doing this because my code is returning a NoneType object

Here are a few examples of classes I have made

This is the parent class:

```
class _DataGroup(object):
    def __init__(self, things=None):
        self._things=things
    
    def __iter__(self):
        for x in self._things:
            yield x
    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._things[key]
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._things)

    def extend(self, datagroup):
        if(isinstance(datagroup, self.__class__)):
            self._things.extend(datagroup._things)
            self._things = list(set(self._things))

    def filterAttribute(self, attribute, value):
        newlist = []
        for thing in self._things:
            if thing._attributes[attribute] == value:
                newlist.append(thing)
        #return self.__init__(newlist)
        return self.__init__(newlist)
```

this is one of the child classes

```
class _AuthorGroup(_DataGroup):
    def __init__(self, things=None):
        self._things = things
    
    def getIDs(self):
        return [x.id for x in self._things]
    
    def getNames(self):
        return [x.name for x in self._things]

    def getWDs(self):
        return [x.wd for x in self._things]
    
    def getUrns(self):
        return [x.urn for x in self._things]

    def filterNames(self, names, incl_none=False):
        newlist = []
        for thing in self._things:
            if((thing is not None or (thing is None and incl_none)) and thing.name in names):
                newlist.append(thing)
        return _AuthorGroup(newlist)
```

The functionality I am looking for is that I can use the parent class's with the child classes and create instances of the child classes instead of the overall DataGroup parent class

Comment: Can `__init__()` return a value other than `None`? Did you want to do something with  `__new__()` rather than `__init__()`? https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__

Comment: Why would you ever want to create an instance of a child class within the parent class?

Comment: @itprorh66 I am creating a data class that holds lists of certain objects, I have general filters that I want all of these lists to be able to filter on, and I have specific filters that only certain classes can do. If I return the parent class I will not have access to the other methods that come with the children. The parent class is abstract and is not supposed to be used just on its own

Comment: @JonSG I will give that a try right now!

Comment: That's why you create a child class it inherits the methods and attributes of the parent. The child can add additional methods and/or over-ride the parent methods.  Thus when you create an instance of a child Class, and utilize super.__init__ within the child class you get the parent class features, there is never a reason to call a child class from within a parent class.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the parent class and a child class

Comment: @itprorh66 Just added some examples to the post, the way I want it to work is that there are methods that they can ALL use that go in the DataGroup class, then all of the other classes are instances of DataGroup and can use the filters but they also have specific fields for the objects that are inputted into them so they have specific methods (like getNames)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I correctly understand what you are trying to accomplish:

- You want a Base Class ****'DataGroup'**** which has a set of defined attributes and methods;
- You want one or mpore child classes with the ability to inherit both methods and attributes from the base class as well as have the ability to over-ride base class methjods if necessary: and
- You want to invoke the child class without also having to manually invoke the base class.

If this in fact is your problem, this is how I would proceed:

***Note:*** I have modified several functions, since I think you have several other issues with your code, for example in the base class self._things is set up as a list, but in the functions **get_item** and filterAttribute you are assuming self._things is a dictionary structure.  I have modified the functions so all assume a dict structure for self._things

```
class _DataGroup:
    def __init__(self, things=None):
        if things == None:
            self._things = dict()  #Sets up default empty dict
        else:
            self._things=things
    
    def __iter__(self):
        for x in self._things.keys():
            yield x
 
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._things)

    def extend(self, datagroup):
        for k, v in datagroup.items():
            nv = self._things.pop(k, [])
            nv.append(v)
            self._things[k] = nv  

# This class utilizes the methods and attributes of DataGroup
# and adds new methods, unique to the child class
class AttributeGroup(_DataGroup):
    def __init__(self, things=None):
        super.__init__(things)
        
    def getIDs(self):
        return [x for x in self._things]
    
    def getNames(self):
        return [x.name for x in self._things]

    def getWDs(self):
        return [x.wd for x in self._things]
    
    def getUrns(self):
        return [x.urn for x in self._things]
 
# This class over-rides a DataGroup method and adds new attribute
class NewChild(_DataGroup):
    def __init__(self, newAttrib, things = None):
        self._newattrib = newAttrib
        super.__init__(self, things)
        
    def __len__(self):
        return max(len(self._newattrib), len(self._things))
```

These examples are simplified, since I am not absolutely sure of what you really want.